# How to set modification date every time NSManagedObject changes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Every time one of my managed objects is modified, I want to store the date it was modified (in an attribute which is already in my data model), for convenience when I'm syncing with other clients.

Is there a way to do this without A) re-writing all my setters manually or B) relying on myself to always change the modification date every single time the object is modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register with the notification center to observe the [NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext%5FClass/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP30001182-237802) notification.

This will tell you what objects are changed. You can check to see if your object is among them and take action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, you can also do this in `-willSave` if you already have a subclass of NSManagedObject.

Comment: only caveat there is that willSave is called every time the object is saved, so you need to do a little extra work to figure out if it was added/modified/deleted. 

The NSManagedObjectContext notifications do this for you and give you NSSets to iterate over.